# Downcasting Exception

Tags: java, downcast

I made this code:

```
protected Lala lala;
private Oyeha oyeha;

public void setLala(Lala lala) {
    this.lala = lala;
}


this.oyeha = (Oyeha) this.lala;
            executeHostBean = this.oyeha.updateMethod(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Lala is the parrent class.

Oyeha is the child which extends Lala.

But when i run this code, i got error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy201

I can't find where my mistake is.
Can somebody help me solve this problem, please? 
Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that `this.lala` is getting set to an instance of Lala which is *not* an instance of Oyeha. Since Oyeha is a subclass of Lala, it's possible to call `public void setLala` with an argument that is an instance of Oyeha, like this:

```
Lala childInstance = new Oyeha();
setLala(childInstance);
```

but it's also possible to call that method with an argument that is just an instance of Lala, like this:

```
Lala parentInstance = new Lala();
setLala(parentInstance);
```

In the first case, `this.lala` is an Oyeha, so you can cast it to Oyeha. But in the latter case,`this.lala` is just a Lala, and your cast of `this.lala` to Oyeha will fail, because a Lala is not an Oyeha.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like Spring injecting the Lala object, it could be creating a dynamic proxy object (that's what the error message suggests).

If downcasting is absolutely necessary in your design, you might want to rethink the design.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answers (they've basically nailed it already):

Suppose you *could* downcast like that, such that the line `this.oyeha = (Oyeha) this.lala`
worked, and there was some field in Oyeha, say, `test`.

If you then tried to use `this.oyeha.test` somewhere, how would it know where `test` is? Even worse, what if instances of `Oyeha` take substantially more memory, and it arbitrarily picks an address outside what was put aside for the instance of `Lala`?

I imagine that the inventors of Java foresaw a situation like that, and thus made it so that you cannot take an instance of a type and cast down to one of its subclasses.

(I would have put this in a comment, but there's too much)